# Find all minima of a list of points

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, filtering

Given a list of points `{x[i],y[i]}` I would like to find all the local minima of `y`

Example:

```
xy = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi 3}, 200] // Sort}];
ListPlot[xy]
```

[image]

I tried to solve this task using `Cases` ,

```
 Cases[xy, {___, {_, a_ }, p : {_, b_ }, {_, c_ }, ___} /;a > b && c > b :> p, All] 
 (*{{4.71476, -0.999997}}*)
```

but Mathematica only returns 1 minimum .

What's wrong with my code?
Perhaps alternative solutions exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) instead of `Cases`:

```
SequenceCases[xy, {{_, a_}, p : {_, b_}, {_, c_}} /; a > b && b < c :> p]

(* Out:
{{4.75359, -0.999151}, {10.8845, -0.993834}, {17.2955, -0.99986}}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know `SequenceCases`. I'm still wondering why `Cases` only returns one minima...

Answer (score 2):

Simple: use `FindPeaks` on `-xy`.  To avoid finding a minimum at the first or the last point, use

```
valleys = 
 xy[[Cases[First /@ FindPeaks[-Last /@ xy], 
    Except[1 | Length[xy], _]]]]

ListPlot[xy, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[valleys]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for this tricky solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[0];

xy = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi 3}, 200] // Sort}];
```

Using `PeakDetect`

```
Rest @ Pick[xy, PeakDetect[-Last /@ xy], 1]
```

{{4.90706, -0.981112}, {11.0208, -0.999682}, {17.2382, -0.999178}}

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[0];

xy = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, RandomReal[{0, 2  Pi  3}, 200] // Sort}];
```

---

Using `ReplaceList`:

```
pts = ReplaceList[xy, {___, {_, a_}, p : {_, b_}, {_, c_}, ___} /; a > b && c > b :> p]

ListLinePlot[xy, PlotStyle -> Blue, Epilog -> {PointSize[0.015], Red, Point[pts]}]

(*{{4.90706, -0.981112}, {11.0208, -0.999682}, {17.2382, -0.999178}}*)
```

[image]

`ReplaceList` is faster compared to `SequenceCases`.